# How to set and overwrite a whole arraylist in firestore

Tags: java, android, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database setup which looks like this.

[image]

I want to overwrite the array students with my new array.

I tried doing it by the set method but I keep getting an error " Invalid data. Unsupported type: Models.students"

Here's my code.

```
 private void update(){
    DocumentReference document = db.collection("Records").document(rid);
        Map students = new HashMap();
        students.put("students", studentsList);
        document.set(students);
    }
```

"studentslist" is an arraylist of students (List< students > studentslist)

**Update**

I solved the issue by implementing what Doug Stevenson suggested

Here's my updated method.

```
private void update(){
       DocumentReference document = db.collection("Records").document(rid);
       List<Map> mapList = new ArrayList<>();
       for(int i=0; i< studentsList.size(); i++){
           Map student = new HashMap();
           student.put("name", studentsList.get(i).getName());
           student.put("id", studentsList.get(i).getId());
           student.put("attended", studentsList.get(i).isAttended());
           mapList.add(student);
       }
       document.update("students", mapList);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore SDK doesn't support writing a field that's an array of POJO style objects.  That's the reason for the error.

Your alternative is to instead write an ArrayList of HashMap objects that each contains the fields and values contained in the POJO.